# python: doctest my github-markdown files?

Tags: python, markdown, doctest, github-flavored-markdown

I'd like to run the doctests from this file, and it's not clear to me out to accomplish it:

`README.md`:

````markdown
# WELCOME!

This library is helpful and will help you in _many_ ways!

For example:

```
>>> import library
>>> library.helps()
True
```
````

*(aside: can anyone help me get this to highlight as markdown?)*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As an alternative to [doctest](https://docs.python.org/3/library/doctest.html) I wrote [mkcodes](https://github.com/ryneeverett/mkcodes), a script that pulls code blocks out of markdown files so they can be tested in a separate file.

Here's my actual test script using mkcodes:

```
mkcodes --github --output tests/docs/test_{name}.py docs
py.test tests
pyflakes tests
pep8 tests
```

Answer (score 12):

You can run `doctest` on your `README` on the command line using:

```
python -m doctest -v README.md
```

The [`-m` parameter](https://docs.python.org/3.6/using/cmdline.html#interface-options) tells Python to run the following module as a script. [When run as a script](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/doctest.html#simple-usage-checking-examples-in-docstrings), the `doctest` module runs the [`doctest.testmod`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/doctest.html#doctest.testmod) function on the following file. Lastly, the `-v` parameter makes `doctest` run in verbose mode; if it's turned off, `doctest` only produces output if at least one test fails (and will produce no output if everything is successful).

Comment: Updating the code may easily make the documentation examples wrong. The test suite should / will tell us when this happens.

Comment: Completely sure is preferable to pretty sure.

Comment: @bukzor Hey, I just got a notification for this answer. I'm not sure why I was so snarky when I originally wrote it. Sorry about that. I just updated my answer to (hopefully) be more helpful/informative.

Comment: This doesn't work with Markdown's fenced code blocks because the ”closing fence” is considered as part of the output/result by the `doctest` module and generates one failure per block.

Answer (score 1):

Just found this [phmdoctest](https://pypi.org/project/phmdoctest/) package which seems to work fine with common python highlighting markdown:

````
Any text here for example...
```python
print(1+2)
```
sample output:
```
3
```
````

and a simple usage:

```
phmdoctest README.md --outfile tests/test_readme.py
python -m pytest tests -v
```

in the first line, you generate a new test file and later just run stand testing for whole your project...

Answer (score 1):

I am the author/owner of phmdoctest mentioned above.

Edit the original question README.md and make sure the fence code blocks you want tested begin with

**```python**

Then run

```
phmutest README.md --replmode --log
```

[phmutest](https://pypi.org/project/phmutest/)

phmutest compared to phmdoctest has these new features:

- Tests all FCBs in the Markdown file as a single example.
- Runs tests internally with Python standard library test runners.
- Caller can provide their own Python initialization and cleanup code.
- Callable from a pytest test case.
- A single example can extend across files.